# wildfly print exceptions in json format

Tags: java, wildfly

What I would like to achieve, is to have json-formatted output (line breaks and indentations) after invoking `deploy` command from `jboss-cli`, because now I get something like this:

```
[standalone@localhost:9990 /] deploy d:\myapp.war

{"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"myapp.war#myPU\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"myapp.war#myPU\": javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: myPU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: JoinTable.name() on a @ToOne association has to be explicit: pwis.bussinesslogic.entities.reviews.AbstractReview.lecture"},"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".compon (...CUT...) myapp.war\".component.ScheduleService.cache]","jboss.deployment.unit.\"myapp.war\".component.ConferencesFacade.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.app]"]}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is actually [DMR](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Detyped+management+and+the+jboss-dmr+library) which does look like JSON, but it's different. I believe it does print a LF, but it looks like you're using Windows which uses LF+CR for a new line. As far as I know there's no way to format the output.